# Quick sort in function

Tags: c

Task: using the function of generating an array to a file, the function of reading an this array, and the quick sort function, sort the read array.

I wrote all the functions, it seems even the sorting is correct. I'm just not sure that elements smaller than the reference are placed to the left of it and more or equal to it are placed to the right.

The question is different - how do I initialize an array if it is already being read by the read function? Errors occur due to variable array conflicts. I tried all sorts of ways - conflict after conflict.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10
#define A -25
#define B 25

void generation();
void read_file(int a[N]);
void qs();

int main(void) {
    generation();
    qs(a, 0, N-1);
}
void qs(int *a, int first, int last) {
    read_file(a);
    if (first < last) {
        int left = first, right = last, middle = a[(left + right) / 2];
        do {
            while (a[left] < middle)
                left++;
            while (a[right] > middle)
                right--;
            if (left <= right) {
                int tmp = a[left];
                a[left] = a[right];
                a[right] = tmp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        } while (left <= right);
        qs(a, first, right);
        qs(a, left, last);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

void generation() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("index.txt", "w");
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%d ", A + rand() % (A - B + 1));
    }
    fclose(file);
}
void read_file(int a[N]) {
    FILE *file;
    int i;
    file = fopen("index.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%d ", &a[i]);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: _"to read this array inside the quick sort function with another function"_ -  this sounds unclear. Can you put the exact task in the question exactly as it's written?

Comment: The READ_FILE function carries an array read from a file. Inside the quick sort function, I have to sort the array that carries READ_FILE.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72054010/edit) the question and put the task, exactly as it's written (not your interpretation of it), in the question.

Comment: I did it moment ago

Comment: If the opening text of this post is the actual, verbatim, task assignment handed to you, you have my sympathy; it is dreadfully written, at-best only partially informative, and highly confusing. Normally one has **a** function to read file content into an array, and another function that sorts the array. the latter is completely agnostic of the former. A `main` would call `read_file` to read the file content into an array, then call `qs` to sort the array, then possibly call another function to write that content back into the same/other file.

Comment: Is the task really written in first person? _"**I** have to sort the array that carries READ_FILE"_?

Comment: Do you mean that I have to read the READ_FILE array in the MAIN function? Then declare another array in the sort function to use another array, let B. Then what to do...I don't really understand how to link them

Comment: Ted, my task in general sounds like this: using the function of generating an array to a file, the function of reading an array, and the quick sort function, sort the read array. 

The teacher makes the assignments himself, so everything sounds crooked and incomprehensible, and I try to explain as best I can!

Comment: _"my task in general sounds like this..."_ - Please edit your question and put the task _exactly_ as it's written in the question.

Comment: I did it moment ago

Comment: _"Task: using the function of generating an array to a file, the function of reading an this array, and the quick sort function, sort the read array."_ - This looks like just random words. I would give up and ask the teacher to clarify the task. I would never accept such an unclear task at work.

Comment: The teacher just shouts and waves his hands, says that everything is clear and easy to implement. 

Let's do it again. The GENERATION function creates an array A[N] in the file INDEX.TXT . Then the READ_FILE(A) function reads into itself the array A[N] created by GENERATION from the file. This array is then sorted in the QS function.

Comment: Does the assignment requires `N` to be fixed (a compile time constant) as in the snippet? Declare the array in `main` and pass it to the functions (one to "generate" or fill it with random numbers, one to write to it to a file, one to read, one to sort... and, maybe, one to check if it's sorted).

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand

Comment: In `main` there is this line: `qs(a, 0, N-1);`. *What* is `a`, here? *Where* is it defined?

Comment: This is an array read from a File using READ_FILE. I thought array A was initialized in READ_FILE, so I wrote qs(a, 0, N-1). Is not it so?

Comment: [Nope](https://godbolt.org/z/Wj18W9qdj).

Comment: Good. You specified in the example the code that declares a specific array in MAIN(). Can I replace it with the READ_FILE function? Will there be something like ```read_file(a)``` because my array is a[N]?  Then, in theory, I will be able to sort this array in QS(), right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The bottom line is that the `main` function did not specify an array, it was necessary to initialize it and reset it in the same function, and then consider it a `read_file(a)` function. Thus, one array is read, it is also sorted.